# Unable to publish Smart Tv app on Samsung Store

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app, smart-tv, smart-tv-alliance

I am trying to publish 'Smart TV' app on 'Samsung Store (Saller Account)', but Its telling that we can not publish Smart Tv app, we can just publish 'Tizen TV' app.

I want to upload 'Smart tv' app. We are developing app in SDK link below.

'http://www.samsungdforum.com/Devtools/SdkDownload'.

Could anybody please help me to get rid this problem.

I am also attaching the message screen sort that Samsung Store (Saller account) showing.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's done because now samsung smart TV have Tizen based OS, so you have to Ist submit tizen app, and once samsung QA passed it and publish it, then only you can publish other version as update for old version.
Just for your information,Converting your app to tizen wont be big issue, there will be minor changes, just try it once

Comment: That means I can publish my app for Tizen OS and after publish, I can update app with old version (Smart TV 2014) support.

Comment: I think, You are understanding different thing. My issue is, I want to publish smart tv app (old version samsung smart tv app 2014 model) but samsung seller account publish only for tizen based app. How to publish Samsung smart tv old version app.

Comment: In other words, you need to publish Tizen app on 2015-2016 devices. After it passes testing, you will be able to upload version for 2010-2014 devices.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung now supporting only tizen sdk based development.